# ServiceStack Ormlite System.Data.IDbConnection' does not contain a definition for 'From'

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

i  was working on  a console application and the word "From" wasn't a problem

```
ex  var Best = db.Select<TopSellingGraph>(
                      db.From<products>
                      .Join<SalesOrderDetail>());
```

but when i start to use the servicestack api i always go into this problem

the error message is Error  1   'System.Data.IDbConnection' does not contain a definition for 'From' and no extension method 'From' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.IDbConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
and i put in the apphost this code

```
var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks"].ConnectionString;
        var conFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(conString, SqlServerDialect.Provider, true);
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => conFactory);
```

i did exactly like the git-hub course

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of OrmLite's APIs are extension methods over ADO.NET's `IDbConnection` interfaces which are made available when using the `ServiceStack.OrmLite` namespace:

```
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
```

Tools like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) help identify, add and can alleviate the burden of dealing with namespaces in C#.